# Upload apk with different signature and same package name in google play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have read lot of similar questions but none of them answered my question
This is first time I am had uploaded an apk in google play store.
I made a mistake by uploading a developer sign key and publishing it to Alpha group.
Now I had unpublished it but it won't let me overwrite a new apk with production key.
Moreover now I can't create a new app in my profile since app with my package name already exists in play store now.
Is their something I can do now? 
I really don't want to change package name, since thousands of users are already using this app from different sources. They need to get this apk with same package name and same production sign key.
Any guidance will be helpful.
Is their some way I can reach out to Google Support team?

Thanks!

EDIT: I had published it using a developer sign key we use internally for testing purpose

Comment: @kuffs It is not a duplicate. Please see my edit. I had used some other key rather than debug key. Can you please answer and do not down vote this question.

Comment: The downvote was not from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, signatures are set forever after your first publish to any channel.  You'll have to create a new app with a new ID in order to get your correctly-signed app on the market.

Comment: As I said, I already tried creating a new app. It won't let me upload the apk since the package name is now already used. remember i have uploaded the debug signed apk with same package name.

Comment: Unfortunately this is how it works. Publish a new app with a new package name\signature or update your current app with the existing package signature. Those are your choices.

Comment: @LoveForDroid When I said "create a new app with a new ID" I mean you need a new application id (aka package name) for the new app.  The original one you can not longer use unless you want to also keep using its debug signature.

Comment: i have signature package name and everything can i make another new application with same package name and signature. will google accept it ?